# Adding list of nodes to another node

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

I have a content type (named "Category") and another content type ("Article"). I want to "Category" nodes have similar functionality as taxonomy term in a way of option to assign "article" nodes to them and display list of "article" nodes teasers on the "Category" page too.

For example: Lets say I have "Category" node named "People". And several "Article" nodes ("Joe", "Frank", "Peter") somehow (part of my question) assigned to "People". When I go to "People" page, I want to see this node content and below also teasers of all assigned "Article" nodes. And I want this not only for a specific node, but for all nodes of content type "Category". How to attain this? Maybe something like taxonomy terms view, but adapted to nodes instead of taxonomy terms?

I know it's easy with taxonomy, but I want to avoid that way - because of buggy taxonomy menu and other things. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use Entity Reference module to create relations between the nodes you need.

https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference

And it works well with Views (for both forward and backward references)

Comment: Thanks for a quick response! :) Entity reference module - ok, i know what you mean. But the Views configuration is the hard part. 

1) I want to views uses URL the same way as taxonomy terms ( = whenever is any node "Category" display, then show this view)
2) How to configure Views to display page as I wrote above

Comment: There are plenty tutorials available on this. Search Youtube and Vimeo.